# What is the best way to read TXT file content and parse it into Erlang tuples?

Tags: parsing, tuples, erlang

I've got a TXT file in the form of tuples:

```
{187,386,858}.
{46,347,621}.
{28,856,354}.
{246,298,574}.
{979,964,424}.
{664,722,318}.
{82,69,64}.
```

I need to read the file, so i get a list of usable tuples to pass `{Key, Num1, Num2}` to a function.

I have tried using `binary:split`, but that doesn't get me quite there:

```
{ok, Device} = file:read_file(Filename),
    Tuples = [binary_to_list(Bin) || Bin <- binary:split(Device,<<".\n">>,[global])].
```

I will get a result like this:

```
["{187,386,858}","{46,347,621}","{28,856,354}",
 "{246,298,574}","{979,964,424}","{664,722,318}",
 "{82,69,64}","{654,351,856}","{185,101,57}","{93,747,166}",
 "{41,442,946}","{444,336,300}","{951,589,376}",
 "{193,987,300}",[]]
```

but looking to get something more in this format:

```
[{979, 193, 224}, {365, 339, 950}, {197, 586, 308},
 {243, 563, 245}, {795, 534, 331}, {227, 736, 701},
 {111, 901, 185}, {303, 178, 461}, {361, 212, 985},
 {149, 659, 496}, {612, 375, 311}, {896, 402, 10}]
```

Answer (score 5):

You have [file:consult/1](https://erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#consult-1) that parses Erlang terms directly from a file.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```erlang
1> Device = <<"{187,386,858}.\n{46,347,621}.\n{28,856,354}.\n{246,298,574}">>.
2> Lists = [binary:split(binary:part(Bin, 1, byte_size(Bin) - 2), <<",">>, [global]) || Bin <- binary:split(Device,<<".\n">>,[global])].
3> Res = [list_to_tuple([binary_to_integer(B) || B <- L]) || L <- Lists].
4> Res.
[{187,386,858},{46,347,621},{28,856,354},{246,298,574}]
```